# Understanding change-making algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was looking for a good solution to the [Change-making problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) and I found this code(Python):

```
target = 200
coins = [1,2,5,10,20,50,100,200]
ways = [1]+[0]*target
for coin in coins:
    for i in range(coin,target+1):
        ways[i]+=ways[i-coin]
print(ways[target])
```

I have no problems understanding what the code literally does,but I can't understand WHY it works. 
Anyone can help?

Comment: On top of all the awesome answers, this https://www.reddit.com/r/algorithms/comments/70wo52/can_someone_please_explain_this_coinchange/ also answers it perfectly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To get all possible sets that elements are equal to 'a' or 'b' or 'c' (our coins) that sum up to 'X' you can:

- Take all such sets that sum up to X-a and add an extra 'a' to each one.
- Take all such sets that sum up to X-b and add an extra 'b' to each one.
- Take all such sets that sum up to X-c and add an extra 'c' to each one.

So number of ways you can get X is sum of numbers of ways you can get X-a and X-b and X-c.

```
ways[i]+=ways[i-coin]
```

Rest is simple recurrence.

Extra hint:
at the start you can get set with sum zero in exactly one way (empty set)

```
ways = [1]+[0]*target
```

Answer (score 10):

This is a classical example of [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). It uses caching to avoid the pitfall of counting things like
3+2 = 5 twice (because of another possible solution: 2+3). A recursive algorithm falls into that pitfall. Let's focus on a simple example, where `target = 5` and `coins = [1,2,3]`. The piece of code you posted counts:

1. 3+2
2. 3+1+1
3. 2+2+1
4. 1+2+1+1
5. 1+1+1+1+1

while the recursive version counts:

1. 3+2
2. 2+3
3. 3+1+1
4. 1+3+1
5. 1+1+3
6. 2+1+2
7. 1+1+2
8. 2+2+1
9. 2+1+1+1
10. 1+2+1+1
11. 1+1+2+1
12. 1+1+1+2
13. 1+1+1+1+1

Recursive code:

```
coinsOptions = [1, 2, 3]
def numberOfWays(target):
    if (target < 0):
        return 0
    elif(target == 0):
        return 1
    else:
        return sum([numberOfWays(target - coin) for coin in coinsOptions])
print numberOfWays(5)
```

Dynamic programming:

```
target = 5
coins = [1,2,3]
ways = [1]+[0]*target
for coin in coins:
    for i in range(coin, target+1):
        ways[i]+=ways[i-coin]
print ways[target]
```

Comment: The recursive approach is wrong. And it's pretty evident why.

Comment: Has it been fixed?

Answer (score 4):

The main idea behind the code is the following:
"On each step there are `ways` ways to make change of `i` amount of money given coins `[1,...coin]`".

So on the first iteration you have only a coin with denomination of `1`. I believe it is evident to see that there is only one way to give a change having only these coins for any target. On this step `ways` array will look like `[1,...1]` (only one way for all targets from `0` to `target`).

On the next step we add a coin with denomination of `2` to the previous set of coins. Now we can calculate how many change combinations there are for each target from `0` to `target`.
Obviously, the number of combination will increase only for targets >= `2` (or new coin added, in general case). So for a target equals `2` the number of combinations will be `ways[2](old)` + `ways[0](new)`. Generally, every time when `i` equals a new coin introduced we need to add `1` to previous number of combinations, where a new combination will consist only from one coin.

For `target` > `2`, the answer will consist of sum of "all combinations of `target` amount having all coins less than `coin`" and "all combinations of `coin` amount having all coins less than `coin` itself".

Here I described two basic steps, but I hope it is easy to generalise it.

Let me show you a computational tree for `target = 4` and `coins=[1,2]`:

> ways[4] given coins=[1,2] =
>
> ways[4] given coins=[1] + ways[2] given coins=[1,2] =
>
> 1 + ways[2] given coins=[1] + ways[0] given coins=[1,2] =
>
> 1 + 1 + 1 = 3

So there are three ways to give a change: `[1,1,1,1], [1,1,2], [2,2]`.

The code given above is completely equivalent to the recursive solution. If you understand [the recursive solution](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change#Recursive_Formulation), I bet you understand the solution given above.

Answer (score -1):

The solution that you posted is summarized version of this code.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// We are going to fill the biggest coins one by one.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="n"> the amount of money </param>
    public static void MakeChange (int n)
    {
        int n1, n2, n3; // residual of amount after each coin
        int quarter, dime, nickel; // These are number of 25c, 10c, 5c, 1c
        for (quarter = n/25; quarter >= 0; quarter--)
        {
            n1 = n - 25 * quarter;
            for (dime = n1/10; dime >= 0; dime--)
            {
                n2 = n1 - 10 * dime;
                for (nickel = n2/5; nickel >= 0 && (n2 - 5*nickel) >= 0; nickel--)
                {
                    n3 = n2 - 5 * nickel;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2},{3}", quarter, dime, nickel, n3); // n3 becomes the number of cent.
                }
            }
        }
    }
```