# Optimization on Python: How do I simplify this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discrete-mathematics, knapsack-problem

I'm new to python, I was trying to solve this optimization problem:

```
    In How many possible ways can I receive 42 emails in 7 days?
```

and I wrote this program in Python to count all the solutions:

```
n = 42
print(n, "emails can be received in the following ways:")
solcount = 0
for d1 in range (n+1):
    for d2 in range (n+1-d1):
        for d3 in range (n+1-d1-d2):
            for d4 in range (n+1-d1-d2-d3):
                for d5 in range (n+1-d1-d2-d3-d4):
                    for d6 in range (n+1-d1-d2-d3-d4-d5):
                        for d7 in range (n+1-d1-d2-d3-d4-d5-d6):
                            if d1+d2+d3+d4+d5+d6+d7 == n:
                                solcount +=1
print("There are", solcount, "possible solutions")
```

where d1 to d7 are the number of emails received on days 1 to 7 respectively.

Now, there are two problems to this:

1. The runtime is ridiculously high, and I suspect that this algorithm
   is far from optimal.
2. The code doesn't allow for me to vary the number of days (like if I were to fix the number of days as a variable *k*).

How do I simplify this?

Thanks!

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Isn't the answer just 42 choose 7? 26978328?

Comment: Is a mathematical expression sufficient or do you really want code to count the number? (A simple expression does exist.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992411/understanding-change-making-algorithm

Comment: Tiny optimisation for the existing approach: no loop for `d7`, because `d7 = n - d1 - d2 - ... - d6`. There is no need to actually evaluate it, just `solcount += 1`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to distinguish the days but not the emails (i.e. you only care how many emails you get on a day but not which particular emails, and you do care which day a particular number of emails arrives) then this is a common [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two) combinatorics problem. You want 7 nonnegative integers whose sum is 42 and the order of the numbers matters. If `nCr(n, k)` is the number of subsets of size `k` taken from a set of size `n`, i.e. the binomial coefficient, then the number you want is

> nCr(42 + 7 - 1, 7 - 1) = 12271512

Here is code that took 19.7 seconds to actually count out that number. The number of days is easily varied by using recursion. This version of my code uses a generator, which you may not have seen yet in your Python studies.

```
def partitions_nonnegative_fixed_length_ordered(n, r):
    """Generate the partitions of the nonnegative integer `n` as the
    sum of `r` nonnegative integers, where the order of the integers
    matters. The partitions are tuples and are generated in
    lexicographic order. The number of partitions generated is
    binomialcoefficient(n+r-1, r-1).
    """
    def partitions_prefixed(prefix, n, r):
        if r == 1:
            yield prefix + (n,)
        else:
            for i in range(n + 1):
                yield from partitions_prefixed(prefix + (i,), n - i, r - 1)

    if n >= 0 and r >= 1 and n == int(n) and r == int(r):
        yield from partitions_prefixed(tuple(), int(n), int(r))

print(sum(1 for v in partitions_nonnegative_fixed_length_ordered(42, 7)))
```

---

If you want to print those partitions (all twelve million of them) rather than just count them, with each partition on a separate line, replace the last line of code with

```
for v in partitions_nonnegative_fixed_length_ordered(42, 7):
    print(v)
```

Comment: Thanks! So, if I have to, additionally, print all the combinations, what else do I have to do?

Comment: @A.K.: See the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by Rory Daulton, this is a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem. I will try to explain it in a simple way, so don't even bother going to wikipedia.

Now, suppose you have only 5 emails to receive in 3 days. The total number of solutions is the same as the anagrams of:

```
"eee|e|e" # represents 3 emails in day1, 1 in day2 and 1 in day3
```

The anagrams can be calculated as the factorial of the number of symbols divided by the product of factorials of the number of times each symbol is repeated. In our simple case:

```
(5 + 3 - 1)!/(5!*(3-1)!)
```

Note we only need 2 bars for three days.

Using this simple argument, you can easily implement a solution like this:

```
from math import factorial

def possibilities(emails, days):
    return factorial(emails + days - 1)//factorial(emails)//factorial(days - 1)
```

This solution is not very efficient because it can calculate really large factorials. You could improve it by looking for a clever way to compute this value, or use a library that provides binomial coefficients for you, like `scipy` or `sympy`.

Comment: Thanks! So, if I have to, additionally, print all the combinations, what else do I have to do?

Comment: Rory's answer is exactly what you need then. It is a generator, if you consume it you would get each 'combination'.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the exact code you want can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem#Implementation) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992411/understanding-change-making-algorithm).